# Android App auto-exit/timeout functionality

Tags: android, timeout, exit

We've been working on a webapp for some time now which is designed to be accessed solely through our Android app.  Obviously, the App itself is extremely lightweight -- mostly providing functionality for creating accounts and logging in, as well as make sure the webapp itself is only accessible through our Android app - BUT I digress...

The app is pretty dependent on PHP Session variables, which expire, and in the current testing environment, if your session expires you just get kicked out to the login screen anyway.  But in production, the login screen will be on the Android app, completely independent of the WebView.

My idea right now is to have a Service run in the background which checks the timestamp we have in the database for a user's last activity, and if it's outside of a certain window, we close the webview.  But if there was someway we could just exit the app after 15 minutes (or whatever) of inactivity--that would be preferable--or at least easier... I think...

Is there a way to do this -- set up an auto timeout exit function?  Or maybe exit the app with the onPause function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My idea right now is to have a Service run in the background which checks the timestamp we have in the database for a user's last activity, and if it's outside of a certain window, we close the webview.

Why a `Service`?

> But if there was someway we could just exit the app after 15 minutes (or whatever) of inactivity--that would be preferable--or at least easier... I think...

You do not want to exit the app. You want to go back to the login screen.

Check the timeout status in `onResume()` of the `WebView`-hosting activity. If the activity is too old, call `startActivity()` for your login screen, then call `finish()` to close up the `WebView`-hosting activity.

Comment: You see, this is why Stackoverflow is my favorite site.  Why in the world would I want to exit the application when I could just go to the login screen...  Just needed a fresh perspective and it all makes perfect sense!  Now, I guess having not actually dove into this yet, is the timeout something that I can set myself in the WebView hosting activity -- i.e. just a timer that runs when the Activity is started? Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: And I assume the timer will continue to run even when the App is in the background?

Comment: @user446882: Why use a timer? Just compare the current timestamp with whatever value represents the "egad! we're expired!" value. If this is purely "inactivity", save the current timestamp in `onPause()` and compare it to the current timestamp in `onResume()`.

Comment: Most ingenious.  I should've figured all of this out... or at least tried on a day when I wasn't sans coffee hahaha

Answer (score -1):

I know this will be considered heresy by Android developers, but this should work:

```
Activity.moveTaskToBack(true);
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```

Still, this would be an absolute last resort.

Comment: Google has repeatedly stated that developers should not do this.

Comment: It's not developers that need to learn this as much as Android users, so Google needs to educate users better. It's amazing how popular the task killers are and how people are convinced they save battery. If people see my app "running" they assume it's using battery and blame my app, and not Google. That's why we need to kill the process.